# GREP REGEX for url having particular start and end with random values in between

Tags: regex, grep, regex-negation

I am having trouble writing a REGEX for my `grep` command. I have a bunch of html pages that need to be searched to find all `youtube.com` links. More importantly, I only need those youtube links that don't end with `rel=0`.

For example:

```
http://www.youtube.com/(something)_rel=0    [i have a regex for this]

http://www.youtube.com/(something)          [i need this one]
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use this grep:

```
grep -i "youtube\." infile | grep -iv "rel=0$"
```